# Mass Cane turned black after major move

Tags: plant-recommendations, tree-care

After moving from South Carolina to New England in February   both my Mass Cane plants turned  black. I have trimmed  it all back, cutting below the rot. I put wax on the newly  cut "stalk" to seal it. I want to repot them. Is it going to grow back or do I move on?

Answer (score 2):

I had a planter given to me with a "dead" mass cane in it. This thing had been though hell and back being left in a garage for 2ish years, no light, no water. Dead plant. I wanted the planter so I took it dead plant and all with gratitude. Life got busy... so my planter and dead plant sat outside for weeks. I finally got around to removing the dead plant and voila! A whole new mass cane had decided to pop up. It's incredibly healthy and already a foot or so tall after only 2 months. These plants should never be given up on. They won't give up on you.